# How to reduce 180 lines of code down to 20 in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a lot of click handler functions which are almost (textually and functionally) identical. I've got a menu with maybe 10 items in it; when I click on an item, the click handler simply makes one `div` visible, and the other 9 `div`'s hidden. Maintaining this is difficult, and I just know there's got to be a smart and/or incomprehensible way to reduce code bloat here. Any ideas how? jQuery is Ok. The code at the moment is:

```
 // repeat this function 10 times, once for each menu item
 $(function() {
   $('#menuItem0').click(function(e) {
     // set 9 divs hidden, 1 visble
     setItem1DivVisible(false);
     // ...repeat for 2 through 9, and then
     setItem0DivVisible(true);
   });
 });

 // repeat this function 10 times, once for each div
 function setItem0DivVisible(on) {
   var ele = document.getElementById("Item0Div");
   ele.style.display = on? "block" : "none";
 }
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle if you want us to write better query selector!

Comment: work with classes. Add an `active` to the element that is clicked and put the according styling into the css. This way you only need one click handler.

Comment: Maybe it'd better posting full code at CodeReview.

Comment: Thanks for all the input - at first sight, all 6 (current) answers seem to work, but I've only gone through 3 of them in detail. The one I accepted isn't the most concise, and requires knowledge of the number of menu items, but it's straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
function addClick(i) {
   $('#menuItem'+i).click(function(e) {
     // set nine divs hidden, 1 visble
       for( var j = 0; j < 10; ++j ) {
           var ele = document.getElementById("Item"+j+"Div");
   ele.style.display = (i == j ? "block" : "none");
       }
   });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create 10 div with a class for marking

```
<div id="id1" class="Testing">....</div>
<div id="id2" class="Testing">....</div>
<div id="id3" class="Testing">....</div>
```

and apply the code

```
$('.Testing').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.Testing').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }    
}
```

Comment: I would go for this simple solution but used "click" instead of "each".

Comment: I'm not sure who upvoted this, but this answer is simply wrong. All this will do is loop through every `.Testing` element and giving it a block display. On the next iteration it'll hide the one it just displayed, meaning the final element will always be shown.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Sorry, i will edit, i forgot to attach the click event :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("div").click(function(){
        // I am using background-color here, because if I use display:none; I won't
        // be able to show the effect; they will all disappear
        $(this).css("background-color","red");
        $(this).siblings().css("background-color", "none");
    });
});
```

Use [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and it makes everything easy. Use it for your menu items with appropriate IDs. This works without any `for` loops or extra classes/markup in your code. And will work even if you add more `div`s.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/Quh74/)

Answer (score 2):

**Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/9XSJW/1/**

It's hard to know without an example of the html.  Assuming that there is no way to traverse from the `menuItem` to `ItemDiv` - you could use `.index` and `.eq` to match up the elements based on the order they match with the selector.

```
var $menuItems = $("#menuItem0, #menuItem1, #menuItem2, ...");
var $divs      = $("#Item0Div, #Item1Div, #Item2Div, ...");

$menuItems.click(function(){
  var idx = $(this).index();

  // hide all the divs
  $divs.hide()

  // show the one matching the index
  .eq(idx).show();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// One click function for all menuItem/n/ elements
$('[id^="menuItem"]').on('click', function() {
    var id = this.id; // Get the ID of the clicked element
    $('[id^="Item"][id$="Div"]').hide(); // Hide all Item/n/Div elements
    $('#Item' + id + 'Div').show(); // Show Item/n/Div related to clicked element
});
```

Obviously this would be much more logical if you were using classes instead:

```html
<elem class="menuItem" data-rel="ItemDiv-1">...</elem>
...
<elem class="ItemDiv" id="ItemDiv-1">...</elem>
```

```js
$('.menuItem').on('click', function() {
    var rel = $(this).data('rel'); // Get related ItemDiv ID
    $('.ItemDiv').hide(); // Hide all ItemDiv elements
    $('#' + rel).show(); // Show ItemDiv related to clicked element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the relevant Id's in an array - `["Item0Div", "Item1Div", ...]`

Create a generic setItemDivVisible method:

```
function setItemDivVisible(visible, id) {
   var ele = document.getElementById(id);
   ele.style.display = visible ? "block" : "none";
}
```

And set your click handler method to be:

```
function(e) {
   var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
   for (var i = 0; i < idsArray.length; i++) {
      setItemDivVisible(idsArray[i] === this.id, idsArray[i]);
   }
}
```

I think this will do the trick